# Application service URL mapping on ABP

Tags: c#, .net-core, abp

I'm new to ABP, and I did [this oficial tutorial](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-1?UI=MVC&DB=EF) succesfully.

The thing is that then I added another class (Planta) and followed the tutorial again (without deleting The Book class), but even when I can create the table and feed data on it (verified), the application fails to load the table, and when I checked the swagger, I found this...

[image]

I was expecting it to be Planta instead of BookAppServicePlanta, and I can't find where did I messed things up.

---

Things I've tryed to solve this

- I have readed the most that I have been able to about ABP.
- I've contrasted every Planta file whith it's Book counterpart.
- I've dropped the database many times.

---

Here is what I did (details below):

1. I created the class planta on `Acme.BookStore.Domain/Planta/Planta.cs`:
2. Added the entity to `Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/BookStoreDbContext.cs`
3. Mapped the entity to the table on `Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/BookStoreDbContextModelCreatingExtensions.cs`
4. Dropped the database, and deleted previous migrations
5. Created a Data Seeder `Acme.BookStore.Domain/BookStoreDataSeederContributor_Plant.cs`
6. Added a new migration, and ran `Acme.BookStore.DbMigrator`
7. Created `Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts/PlantDto.cs`
8. Added it to the `Acme.BookStore.Application/BookStoreApplicationAutoMapperProfile.cs`
9. created `Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts/CreateUpdatePlantDto.cs` (and added it too to the automapper as shown on 8) )
10. created the interface `Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts/IBookAppServicePlanta.cs`
11. Implemented it on `Acme.BookStore.Application/BookAppServicePlanta.cs`
12. Ran the application

---

Extra Info:
I created the pages for Planta and its forms (tutorial part 2 and 3), but even I've double checked those files, I dont belive the problem is on those files, since swagger problem.

---

1. I created the class planta on `Acme.BookStore.Domain/Planta/Planta.cs`:

   ```
    using System;
    using Volo.Abp.Domain.Entities.Auditing;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
    {
        public class Planta : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
        {
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }
            public string Dirección { get; set; }
            public string Lat { get; set; }
            public string Long { get; set; }
            public string Extra1 { get; set; }
            public string Extra2 { get; set; }
            public string Extra3 { get; set; }

        }
    }
   ```
2. Added the entity to `Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/BookStoreDbContext.cs`

   ```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Acme.BookStore.Users;
    using Volo.Abp.Data;
    using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Modeling;
    using Volo.Abp.Identity;
    using Volo.Abp.Users.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Acme.BookStore.Books;
    using Acme.BookStore.Plantas;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore
    {
        /* This is your actual DbContext used on runtime.
         * It includes only your entities.
         * It does not include entities of the used modules, because each module has already
         * its own DbContext class. If you want to share some database tables with the used modules,
         * just create a structure like done for AppUser.
         *
         * Don't use this DbContext for database migrations since it does not contain tables of the
         * used modules (as explained above). See BookStoreMigrationsDbContext for migrations.
         */
        [ConnectionStringName("Default")]
        public class BookStoreDbContext : AbpDbContext<BookStoreDbContext>
        {
            public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Planta> Plantas { get; set; }

            /* Add DbSet properties for your Aggregate Roots / Entities here.
             * Also map them inside BookStoreDbContextModelCreatingExtensions.ConfigureBookStore
             */

            public BookStoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<BookStoreDbContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {

            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);

                /* Configure the shared tables (with included modules) here */

                builder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
                {
                    b.ToTable(AbpIdentityDbProperties.DbTablePrefix + "Users"); //Sharing the same table "AbpUsers" with the IdentityUser

                    b.ConfigureByConvention();
                    b.ConfigureAbpUser();

                    /* Configure mappings for your additional properties
                     * Also see the BookStoreEfCoreEntityExtensionMappings class
                     */
                });

                /* Configure your own tables/entities inside the ConfigureBookStore method */

                builder.ConfigureBookStore();
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Mapped the entity to the table on `Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/BookStoreDbContextModelCreatingExtensions.cs`

   ```
    using Acme.BookStore.Books;
    using Acme.BookStore.Plantas;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Volo.Abp;
    using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Modeling;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.EntityFrameworkCore
    {
        public static class BookStoreDbContextModelCreatingExtensions
        {
            public static void ConfigureBookStore(this ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                Check.NotNull(builder, nameof(builder));

                /* Configure your own tables/entities inside here */

                builder.Entity<Book>(b =>
                {
                    b.ToTable(BookStoreConsts.DbTablePrefix + "Books",
                              BookStoreConsts.DbSchema);
                    b.ConfigureByConvention(); //auto configure for the base class props
                    b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
                });

                builder.Entity<Planta>(p =>
                {
                    p.ToTable(BookStoreConsts.DbTablePrefix + "Plantas",
                              BookStoreConsts.DbSchema);
                    p.ConfigureByConvention(); //auto configure for the base class props
                    p.Property(y => y.Nombre).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
                });
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Dropped the database, and deleted previous migrations
5. Created a Data Seeder `Acme.BookStore.Domain/BookStoreDataSeederContributor_Plant.cs`

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Acme.BookStore.Plantas;
    using Volo.Abp.Data;
    using Volo.Abp.DependencyInjection;
    using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;

    namespace Acme.BookStore
    {
        public class BookStoreDataSeederContributor_Plant
            : IDataSeedContributor, ITransientDependency
        {
            private readonly IRepository<Planta, Guid> _plantaRepository;

            public BookStoreDataSeederContributor_Plant(IRepository<Planta, Guid> plantaRepository)
            {
                _plantaRepository = plantaRepository;
            }

            public async Task SeedAsync(DataSeedContext context)
            {
                if (await _plantaRepository.GetCountAsync() > 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                await _plantaRepository.InsertAsync(
                    new Planta
                    {
                        Nombre = "Armijo Guajardo",
                        Descripcion = "excel god",
                        Dirección = "las lilas 123",
                        Lat = "564.765.98",
                        Long  = "100.102.04",
                        Extra1 = "bla",
                        Extra2 = "bla bla",
                        Extra3 = "bla bla bla"
                    },
                    autoSave: true
                );
            }
        }
    }
   ```
6. Added a new migration, and ran `Acme.BookStore.DbMigrator`
7. Created `Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts/PlantDto.cs`

   ```
    using System;
    using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
    {
        public class PlantDto : AuditedEntityDto<Guid>
        {
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }
            public string Dirección { get; set; }
            public string Lat { get; set; }
            public string Long { get; set; }
            public string Extra1 { get; set; }
            public string Extra2 { get; set; }
            public string Extra3 { get; set; }
        }
    }
   ```
8. Added it to the `Acme.BookStore.Application/BookStoreApplicationAutoMapperProfile.cs`

   ```
    using Acme.BookStore.Books;
    using Acme.BookStore.Plantas;
    using AutoMapper;

    namespace Acme.BookStore
    {
        public class BookStoreApplicationAutoMapperProfile : Profile
        {
            public BookStoreApplicationAutoMapperProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<Book, BookDto>();
                CreateMap<CreateUpdateBookDto, Book>();
                CreateMap<Planta, PlantDto>();
                CreateMap<CreateUpdatePlantDto, Planta>();
            }
        }
    }
   ```
9. created `Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts/CreateUpdatePlantDto.cs` (and added it too to the automapper as shown on 8) )

   ```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
    {
        public class CreateUpdatePlantDto
        {
            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Nombre { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Dirección { get; set; }
            [Required]

            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Lat { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Long { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Extra1 { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Extra2 { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(128)]
            public string Extra3 { get; set; }
        }
    }
   ```
10. created the interface `Acme.BookStore.Application.Contracts/IBookAppServicePlanta.cs`

    ```
    using System;
    using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
    using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
    {
        public interface IBookAppServicePlanta :
            ICrudAppService< //Defines CRUD methods
                PlantDto, //Used to show books
                Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
                PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting
                CreateUpdatePlantDto> //Used to create/update a book
        {

        }
    }
    ```
11. Implemented it on `Acme.BookStore.Application/BookAppServicePlanta.cs`

    ```
    using System;
    using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
    using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;
    using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;


    namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
    {
        public class BookAppServicePlanta :
            CrudAppService<
                Planta, //The Book entity
                PlantDto, //Used to show books
                Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
                PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting
                CreateUpdatePlantDto>, //Used to create/update a book
            IBookAppServicePlanta //implement the IBookAppService
        {
            public BookAppServicePlanta(IRepository<Planta, Guid> repository)
                : base(repository)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    ```
12. Ran the application

---

[EDIT]

`Acme.BookStore.Web/BookStoreWebAutoMapperProfile.cs` looks like this

```
    using Acme.BookStore.Books;
    using Acme.BookStore.Plantas;
    using AutoMapper;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.Web
    {
        public class BookStoreWebAutoMapperProfile : Profile
        {
            public BookStoreWebAutoMapperProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<BookDto, CreateUpdateBookDto>();
                CreateMap<PlantDto, CreateUpdatePlantDto>();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

[EDIT]
I created a teting file `Acme.BookStore.Application.Tests/BookAppServicePlanta_test.cs`, and they all succeded.

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Shouldly;
    using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
    using Volo.Abp.Validation;
    using Xunit;

    namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
    {
        public class BookAppService_Tests : BookStoreApplicationTestBase
        {
            private readonly IBookAppServicePlanta _plantaAppService;

            public BookAppService_Tests()
            {
                _plantaAppService = GetRequiredService<IBookAppServicePlanta>();
            }

            [Fact]
            public async Task Should_Get_List_Of_Books()
            {
                //Act
                var result = await _plantaAppService.GetListAsync(
                    new PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto()
                );

                //Assert
                result.TotalCount.ShouldBeGreaterThan(0);
                result.Items.ShouldContain(b => b.Nombre == "Armijo Guajardo");
            }

            [Fact]
            public async Task Should_Create_A_Valid_Planta()
            {
                //Act
                var result = await _plantaAppService.CreateAsync(
                    new CreateUpdatePlantDto
                    {
                        Nombre = "Pedro Cano",
                        Descripcion = "Cirujano",
                        Dirección = "Pedro de Valdivia",
                        Lat = "123213213",
                        Long = "456456456",
                        Extra1 = "emmmm",
                        Extra2 = "no se",
                        Extra3 = "que poner"
                    }
                );

                //Assert
                result.Id.ShouldNotBe(Guid.Empty);
                result.Nombre.ShouldBe("Pedro Cano");
            }
            [Fact]
            public async Task Should_Not_Create_A_Planta_Without_Name()
            {
                var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<AbpValidationException>(async () =>
                {
                    await _plantaAppService.CreateAsync(
                        new CreateUpdatePlantDto
                        {
                            Descripcion = "Cirujano",
                            Dirección = "Pedro de Valdivia",
                            Lat = "123213213",
                            Long = "456456456",
                            Extra1 = "emmmm",
                            Extra2 = "no se",
                            Extra3 = "que poner"
                        }
                    );
                });
                exception.ValidationErrors
                    .ShouldContain(err => err.MemberNames.Any(mem => mem == "Nombre"));
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with ABP, but from a quick view to the documentation, it appears that you are not following the naming convention.

The application services should follow this naming convention: `Entity`AppService

But it appears you copied/pasted the previous class `BookAppService` and just added `Planta` to the end. It should be `PlantaAppService` instead.

```
using System;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;

namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
{
    public interface IPlantaAppService :
        ICrudAppService< //Defines CRUD methods
            PlantDto, //Used to show books
            Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
            PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting
            CreateUpdatePlantDto> //Used to create/update a book
    {

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;
using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;


namespace Acme.BookStore.Plantas
{
    public class PlantaAppService:
        CrudAppService<
            Planta, //The Book entity
            PlantDto, //Used to show books
            Guid, //Primary key of the book entity
            PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting
            CreateUpdatePlantDto>, //Used to create/update a book
        IPlantaAppService //implement the IPlantaAppService
    {
        public BookAppServicePlanta(IRepository<Planta, Guid> repository)
            : base(repository)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, thanks!
I thought naming convention was more of a best practice for easyer debug than an actual requisite for things work.
I'll pay more atention to this in the future